# How to render partial with different model data to other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, partials

At this moment I am at products/index page, I have set up layout so now at the left side I have menu where I can choose between multiple categories. These are links, so when I click on them I am redirected to categories controller with specific categegory.

But I wan't to just render category controllers action show with specific category.
Is that possible, I need just a tip, I don't need full answer :)

Thanks

Comment: what you want to implement actually..? as soon as click on category link, it will go to categories#index method. And you want to render products#index view.. right..?

Comment: @Jyothu I wan't to implement that clicking on left menu would render partial on that same products controller. Partial would consist of other controller data, such subcategories. At the menu I can choose Product categories, clicking that would render subcategories of the main category at the same page, but now I have like, clicking on menu redirects to different controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in side bar

```
<%= link_to products_path(:category => cat.id) %>
```

in products#index

```
@category = Category.find params[:category]
```

in products/index.html.erb

```
<% render '/categories/category' if @category.present? %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Couldn't find Category without an ID` Its because off the this metod that generates link_to these categories, how can I merge this kind off functionallity ?

`<ul id="menuks">`

`<li id="auctions">Atkritumu pārstrādes tehnika</li>`
    `<% @children1.each do |o|%>`
        `<li class="submenuks"> <%= link_to (o.name), o %></li>`
        `<%end%>`

`</ul>`

Comment: @rhernando This is for You. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @rhernando I found solution.

Controller

`@category = Category.find_by_name(params[:category])`

Side menu

```
<li id="auctions">Atkritumu pārstrādes tehnika</li>
<% @children1.each do |o|%>
    <li class="submenuks"> <%= link_to (o.name), products_path(:category => o.name) %></li>
    <%end%>
```